# Using nuptial knot in sentence

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrases

Which is correct for marriage
tying the nuptial knot
or tying the knot , are both same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. Which one you use depends on how much detail and and clarity you need to provide.

"Tying the knot" is a well known expression meaning to get married, so unless there is some danger of confusion with tying a literal knot, or you think the hearer/reader will not understand the expression, then it is OK to use it in its own. If you think extra claruficationbis needed add nuptial.

Comment: "Nuptial knot" is also more poetic.